# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, async-iterator

I'm studying Async iterators and generators from this wonderful [page](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/async-iterators-and-generators/), but when I try to use the following "simple" code...

```
  // Note the * after "function"
  async function* asyncRandomNumbers() {
    // This is a web service that returns a random number
    const url = 'https://www.random.org/decimal-fractions/?num=1&dec=10&col=1&format=plain&rnd=new';

    while (true) {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const text = await response.text();
      yield Number(text);
    }
  }

  async function example() {
    for await (const number of asyncRandomNumbers()) {
      console.log(number);
      if (number > 0.95) break;
    }
  }

  example();
```

... my React app returns me this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

The error message refers to this line:

```
async function example() {
^
```

If used directly on console of various browsers it does not give me any problems.

Why is that? How can I use it in React?

EDIT

I'm using [expo](https://expo.io/) to build my app.

Comment: Are you using any kind of transpiler?

Comment: I'm using [expo](https://expo.io/) to build my app